# P almost continuous version of a stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, stochastic-processes

I am studying continuous stochastic processes and I would like to show that if my stochastic process $X$ satisfies the hypothesis of the well known Kolmogorov continuity theorem, I can find a set $A$ with $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$ on which $X_{t}(.)$ is $\delta$ Holdër continuous.

Here is the important part of the Kolmogorov continuity theorem that I use to show this (that is the existence of a modification\version $Y$ satisfying the following inequality) :

> Given assumptions we assume here on a stochastic process $X$, there exists a version $Y$ of $X$ satisfying for all $\delta\in[0, \frac{\beta}{\alpha}[$
> $$
> \mathbb{E}\Big[\Big(\sup\Big\{\frac{\lvert Y_s - Y_t\rvert}{\lvert s -t\rvert^{\delta}} : s\neq t\in [0,1]\Big\}\Big)^{\alpha}\Big]<\infty.
> $$

where $\alpha,\beta>0$.

Here is my attempt :

I denote $k_{\delta} := \sup\big\{\frac{\lvert Y_s - Y_t\rvert}{\lvert s -t\rvert^{\delta}} : s\neq t\in [0,1]\big\}$. This random variable is finite almost surely from the theorem. Thus, we have
$$
\mathbb{P}\Big(\omega \,\big\vert\, \forall\delta\in[0,\frac{\beta}{\alpha}[, \forall s\neq t\in[0,1] : \frac{\lvert Y_s(\omega)- Y_t(\omega)\rvert}{\lvert s -t\rvert^{\delta}}\leq k_{\delta}(\omega)\Big).
$$

By continuity of the process, we have

$$
\mathbb{P}\Big(\bigcap_{s\neq t\in [0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\bigcap_{\delta\,\in\, [0,\frac{\beta}{\alpha}[\,\cap\,\mathbb{Q}}\big\{\omega :\lvert Y_s(\omega)- Y_t(\omega)\rvert\leq k_{\delta}(\omega)\lvert s -t\rvert^{\delta}\big\}\Big).
$$

From there, I don’t know how to proceed. I would like to take out the intersection and transform it as a limit, but I cannot justify this.

I would like to know if what I have done so far is okay, and, if not, how to improve it. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I think you're missing some "$=1$"s?

Comment: @NateEldredge You are right ! I have in mind that this set $\big\{\omega :\lvert Y_s(\omega)- Y_t(\omega)\rvert\leq k_{\delta}(\omega)\lvert s -t\rvert^{\delta}<\infty\big\}$ has probability $1$ and I would like to use it by putting outside the probability the intersection, am I right ?

Comment: Just to clarify, your goal here is to show "for all $\delta \in [0,\frac{\beta}{\alpha}[$, $Y$ is $\delta$-Holder continuous almost surely," right?  It may also help to edit your question to add what $\beta$ and $\alpha$ are.

Comment: @user6247850 Very sorry my post was unclear. My aim is to show that if there exists a version $Y$ of $X$ satisfying the condition I stated, then there exists a set with probability 1 under which $X$ is continuous and even better Holdër continuous. Let me know if I am still unclear please. ( I have updated the post )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear up a misconception, Kolmgorov's continuity theorem does not guarantee that there exists a set $A$ with $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1$ on which $t \mapsto X_t$ is continuous.  Rather, it guarantees that there exists a continuous process $Y$ such that, for all $t \ge 0$, $\mathbb{P}(Y_t = X_t) = 1$.  The important distinction is that $\{\omega : Y_t(\omega) = X_t(\omega)\}$ may be different for each $t$.

From what I understand of your question, you've shown that there exists a version $Y$ of $X$ satisfying $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left( \sup_{s \ne t \in [0,1]} \frac{|Y_t-Y_s|}{|t-s|^{\delta}}\right)^{\alpha} \right] < \infty$$ for all $\delta \in [0,\frac{\beta}{\alpha}[$, and what remains is to show that this version is Holder-continuous almost surely.

As a reminder, that means we want to show that for almost every $\omega$, we have that there exists constants $p = p(\omega) > 0$ and $C = C(\omega) < \infty$ (possibly depending on $\omega$) such that $|Y_t(\omega)-Y_s(\omega)| \le C |t-s|^p$ for all $t,s \in [0,1]$.

Using your definition of $k_\delta(\omega) := \sup_{s \ne t \in [0,1]} \frac{|Y_t(\omega)-Y_s(\omega)|}{|t-s|^{\delta}}$, we have immediately that $|Y_t(\omega)-Y_s(\omega)| \le k_\delta(\omega) |t-s|^\delta$ for all $t,s \in [0,1]$ just from the definition of $k_\delta$.  Since $\mathbb{P}(k_\delta<\infty) = 1$, we conclude that we do indeed have that $Y$ is Holder-continuous almost surely.  Even better, we have that it is almost surely $\delta$-Holder continuous for all $\delta \in [0,\frac{\beta}{\alpha}[$.

As an example to show we only have continuity of a modification, consider $\Omega = [0,1]$ with $\mathbb{P}$ equal to the Lebesgue measure, and define $X_t(\omega) = t1_{t \ne \omega}$.  Then, for all $t,s \in [0,1]$, we have $\mathbb{E}[|X_t-X_s|^\alpha] = |t-s|^{\alpha}$, so Kolmgorov's continuity theorem applies and we can find a Holder continuous modification (namely $Y_t(\omega) = t$).  However, for every $\omega \in \Omega$, the path $t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ has a discontinuity on $[0,1]$, so there is no chance of finding a set with probability $1$ on which $X$ is continuous (Holder or otherwise).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Concerning the misconception, it was what I have understood of the following exercice : « Prove that under Kolmogorov continuity theorem, there exists a set $A$ with $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1$ such that for all $\omega\in A$, the trajectory $t\in[0,1]\to X_{t}(\omega)$ is $\delta$ Holdër continuous for all $\delta\in [0, \frac{\beta}{\alpha}[$. » Which seems (to me) to be exactly what you have said to be not a consequence of the Kolmogorov continuity theorem so I have some doubt either on the exercise or on my comprehension of what you have said ?

Comment: @coboy I think the exercise is mistaken, unless it is using $X_t$ to refer to the modification rather than the original process.  Could you let me know where you found it?

Comment: @coboy I added an example showing that Kolmogorov's continuity theorem can apply to a process which has no continuous trajectories

Comment: Thank you for your answer and especially the example ! To be sure I understand well the latter, the only $\omega$ for which $X_t(\omega)$ is continuous is $0$ ?

Comment: @coboy Yes, that's correct.  You could probably do something like $X_t(\omega) = 1_{t+\omega \in \mathbb{Q}}$ to get something that is nowhere continuous for all $\omega$ but has a continuous modification

Comment: Thank you this is clear ! A last question about the computation of the expectation of $\lvert X_t -X_s\rvert^{\alpha}$ how do you obtain this please ? At first it was very intuitive but when I tried not so… For sure you use the change of variable formula but after I don’t see  how to continue ? I get this for the moment $\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}\lvert t1_{\omega\neq t} - s1_{\omega\neq s}\rvert^{\alpha}d(\lambda_1\otimes\lambda_2)(\omega)$ ?

Comment: @coboy It's just that $|X_t-X_s| = |t-s|$ a.s., and if two functions are equal except on a set of measure $0$ then their integrals are equal.  They both use the same sample space, so if you wanted to write it as an integral it would be $\int_{[0,1]} |t1_{\omega \ne t} - s 1_{\omega \ne s}|^\alpha d\lambda(\omega)$.

Comment: Thank you ! I always use a change of variable when I have the expectation of two random variables but here it is not so interesting indeed since the sample space is explicit ($[0,1]$) !